# How to retrieve related values from 2 different mysql tables (check the example)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables like following.

Table1 : subjectcodes

```
guideno  |  subcode
--------------------
   1     |  11
   1     |  22
   2     |  33
   2     |  44
   3     |  11
   3     |  55
```

Table2 : seniority

```
 no  |  guideno
---------------------
  1  |   1
  2  |   2
```

I wish to find the guideno from table seniority with subcode same as any of  subcodes of guideno 3's.

That is the result is : guidenno 1 (Because guideno 3 and 1 have same subject code 11)

It's burning my head. Any ideas for a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it with simple join..

Comment: Am a beginner to mysql would you pls post the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM subjectcodes x 
  JOIN subjectcodes y 
    ON y.subcode = x.subcode 
   AND y.guideno <> x.guideno 
 WHERE y.guideno = 3;
```